# android input method problems

Tags: android, ime, android-input-method

A few questions about android:

Is it possible to replace the keys in default keyboards ? For example, is it possible to replace the dot in the numeric keyboard with a comma ?

I wrote a very simple IME, but I cannot set it to an EditText. What I want is to set one of my  EditText to use the IME I wrote by default, not the default LatinIME. Is that possible ? How inputMethod attribute works ? I set the fully qualified class name of IME but it raises class not found exception.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
Is it possible to replace the keys in default keyboards ?
```

You don't. Users are in control over their device, including what keyboard gets used.

But You can try to make some input methods

Read this tutorial: [Creating an Input Method](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html)

clone this repo: [LatinIME](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME.git;a=summary)

And if replacing one character is your requirement, you can override text change listener of edittext, and check each entered character and if user entered dot then replace that with comma as

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           //Check if s contains dot and replace it with comma
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    });
```

But this method executes each key hit in EditText.

Comment: That is what we are doing now, but this does not help much because the key in keyboard is still same (dot in our case not comma). I tried to write an input method, but I cannot set it to my edit text by default. Have you tried this before ?

Comment: I didn't do the same. But I did char replacement before in same way as I discussed, and I was able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

try override this method.return another keyCode and see the reslt

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == someKeyCode) {
          //...... button is pressed
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: I did not think this before, but we are already using a TextWatcher to replace the chars we dont want with others. But this does not help much, as my comment above because the key in keyboard is still same.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure replacing keys in the default keyboard is not possible, you would need to write your own keyboard replacement, much like all the keyboard Apps do.

Comment: By keyboard replacement do you mean making an input method ? If so, I cannot set it to my edit text by default. Have you did this before ?